# Subprocess fails to print esxcli namespace correctly

Tags: python, subprocess, vmware, vsphere

When I execute esxcli from the commandline, a command such as

```
esxcli --server=222.222.222.222 --username=foo@user.local --password='bar' --vihost=111.111.111.111 network vswitch standard portgroup add -p vlan1 -v switch1
```

works fine. Calling from subprocess however always fails because it cannot recognize the namespace. This is because it puts the namespace and command in quotes, instead of adding it directly. My current code from the subprocess call is:

```
import settings
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["esxcli",
                 "--server="+ settings.vserver,
                 "--username="+ settings.user,
                 "--password=\'"+ settings.pwd + "\'",
                 "--vihost="+ settings.host,
                 "network vswitch standard portgroup add",
                 "-p "+ settings.newpgname,
                 "-v "+ settings.newpgswitch])
```

When I run `subprocess.list2cmdline`, I get:

```
esxcli --server=222.222.222.222 --username=foo@user.local --password='bar' --vihost=111.111.111.111 "network vswitch standard portgroup add" "-p vlan1" "-v switch1"
```

Note that the namespace and the arguments after it are all in quotations.

Most of the questions I've found about subprocess deal with shell=True, not anything about additional non hyphen-prefixed arguments.

How can I make subprocess run the correct command, without the extra quotes?

Comment: I ended up just using the old os.system call instead.

Comment: to see how the proper argument list should look like, call `shlex.split(shell_command)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code, you're saying that fifth argument to the executable should be the string **"network vswitch standard portgroup add"**.  In order to pass that on the command line, it has to be quoted.  Instead, you should make those be separate arguments, just like they would be on the command line.  The same applies for the flag arguments; the executable doesn't expect a single argument **"-v switch1"**, but rather two arguments **"-v"** and **"switch1"**.  Thus you should do:

```
subprocess.call(["esxcli",
                 "--server="+settings.vserver,
                 "--username="+settings.user,
                 "--password="+settings.pwd,
                 "--vihost="+settings.host,
                 "network","vswitch","standard","portgroup","add",
                 "-p",settings.newpgname,
                 "-v",settings.newpgswitch])
```

Comment: It is incorrect. It should be: one command-line argument <-> one list item i.e., OP already specified `"network vswitch.."` argument correctly. There are other errors e.g., erroneous quotes, it should be: `"--password", setting.pwd` instead (no quotes).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm not sure I follow.  If there's should be one list item per command line argument, then surely the list should contain  the five elements `"network","vswitch","standard","portgroup","add"` rather than the one `"network vswitch standard portgroup add"`, right?  And I'm inclined to agree with you on `"--password",setting.pwd` (which I believe works), but because OP said the original command included `--password='bar'`, which would be just one command line argument, I preserved that style.

Comment: my mistake, I've looked at the second line (where it is in quotes), instead of the first. The quotes  around `bar` should be removed (as the shell does) because `subprocess` doesn't start the shell by default (you are passing the wrong password to the command).

Comment: to clarify: passing `--password='bar'` to the subprocess directly is *your* mistake (no shell to strip the quotes).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Oh, yes, that's definitely a bug.  I've fixed it.  Personally, I'd still prefer a version with no string concatenation at all.  The `=` isn't necessary, so it'd be cleaner and easier to just do `[...,'-password',settings.pwd,...']`.

Comment: I agree. Though it depends on the program whether `'--option=value'` is equivalent to `'--option', 'value'` (it should but it is not always so).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Upvote on that last comment.  I just happened to know that about esxcli because I've been using it recently.  You're right though, that `'--option=value` should only be replaced with `--option`,`value` if the program handles them equivalently.